# delete files instead of moving to wastebasket

Tags: raspbian, file

How to delete files in folders instead of moving to waste basket?  When I right click file it only gives option to move to waste basket.  Want to do this in GUI and not terminal.

Comment: nice job dirk nowitzki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Raspbian...

Use [shift+delete]. And on right click: if you press [shift] after the menu opens, the option `Move to Wastebasket` changes to `Remove`.

Comment: can u set the default to remove or no?

Comment: Sort of: you can switch off the wastebasket completely (Preferences / General / Move to Wastebasket)